# Comparing data in two rows from same DB2 table

Tags: db2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vdAp.png) Can someone suggest me with the query for comparing two rows in the same DB2 table.The query result has to display the mismatched column name and values.

Comment: There is no notion of comparing two rows without an ordering or a column which allows us to discriminate one row from the other.  Please include sample table data.

Comment: Lets say we have a table Records with fields Record_type, record_name, update_date, file_id . based on file_id I need to compare.

Comment: Which column(s) determine whether two records are logically the same thing?

Comment: file_id column .  I  will have two different file_id but the other column values has to be same.

Comment: No... if the `file_id` and other columns are not the same, then we can't correlate your pairs.  Add some sample data please.

Comment: You may want to provide your table definition, some sample data, expected output, and the queries you've tried so far. As it stands, it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: You can use 'GROUP BY' on rest of the columns 'Record_type, record_name, update_date' to get different 'file_id' values. I am Not sure what you really want to do with the result.

Comment: Actually, one file will be from DB2 and other file will be Hadoop environment based on file_id column I can find the difference whether it is a Hadoop file or Db2 file and I need to compare the rest of the rows